# Moving an elasticsearch index of one node in a machine to another drive of the same machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch node in a machine with a 150gb ssd and a 3 tb hdd. Since I am running out of space in the ssd, I would like to move one index from the ssd to the hdd. Is this possible? If so how?

I could create another node on the hdd, but I'd rather have one node in the machine...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely move the data directory (and individual indexes and even shards) around. We've scp'd entire indexes around in this manner.

You probably should not actively index or delete when you are doing this though, or unpredictable things could happen.

Once you do the move, you just need to tell elasticsearch where to find data directory. You set this in the elasticsearch config file found in /etc/elasticsearch

Just add this setting:

```
path:
  logs: /path/to/log/files
  data: /path/to/data/directory
```

You might want to cp and not mv, just in case things don't go as planed.

Comment: Side note: disable flush while copying indices around, to make sure you get a consistent copy of the lucene indices. And don't forget to re-enable flush at the end.